# Unknown exception in SendMail method: List index out of bounds

Tags: apex, exception, send-email, b2b-commerce

I am facing the current error with the Messaging.sendEmail method:

> Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, List index out of bounds: 0: []

The code responsible for processing and sending the email message is below:

```
global static void notify(List<ccrz__E_Order__c> orders, String type) {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
    if (type == 'confirmed') {
        messages.addAll(mountEmailMessages(orders, 'Syn_Order_Confirmed'));
    } else if (type == 'shipped') {
        messages.addAll(mountEmailMessages(orders, 'Syn_Order_Shipped'));
    } else if (type == 'submitted') {
        messages.addAll(mountEmailMessages(orders, 'Syn_Order_Submitted'));
        messages.addAll(mountEmailMessages(orders, 'Syn_Order_Acknowledged'));
    }

    System.debug('@messages => ' + messages);
    
    if(!Test.isRunningTest())List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> result = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
}

private static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mountEmailMessages(List<ccrz__E_Order__c> orders, String templateName) {
    Map<String, List<Contact>> orderContactMap = new Map<String, List<Contact>>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWideAddresses = [SELECT Id, Address FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName = 'Pedido Loja'];
    List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =: templateName];
    
    if (templateName == 'Syn_Order_Acknowledged') {
        orderContactMap.putAll(fetchContacts(orders));
    }
    
    for (ccrz__E_Order__c order : orders) {
        if (templateName == 'Syn_Order_Acknowledged') {
            List<Contact> contacts = orderContactMap.get(order.Id);
            if(contacts != null){
                for (Contact c : contacts) {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    System.debug('@contact => ' + c.Id);
                    msg.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);
                    
                    if (!orgWideAddresses.isEmpty())
                        msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideAddresses.get(0).Id);
                    System.debug('@orgWide => ' + orgWideAddresses.get(0).Id);
                    
                    if (!templates.isEmpty()) 
                        msg.setTemplateId(templates.get(0).Id);
                    System.debug('@template => ' + templates.get(0).Id);
                    
                    
                    System.debug('@order => ' + order.Id);
                    msg.setWhatId(order.Id);
                    
                    msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    messages.add(msg);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            msg.setTargetObjectId(order.ccrz__User__c);
            System.debug('@user => ' + order.ccrz__User__c);
            
            if (!orgWideAddresses.isEmpty())
                msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideAddresses.get(0).Id);
            System.debug('@orgWide => ' + orgWideAddresses.get(0).Id);
            
            if (!templates.isEmpty()) 
                msg.setTemplateId(templates.get(0).Id);
            System.debug('@template => ' + templates.get(0).Id);
            
            msg.setWhatId(order.Id);
            System.debug('@order => ' + order.Id);
            
            msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            messages.add(msg);
        }
    } 
    
    return messages;
}
```

The code above is invoked through Process Builder on the creation/edit of **CC Order** sObject records. For older **CC Order** (like, older than 10-22-2020) records the process is working like a charm. Only for new records that this problem is happening.

Could you help me to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Can you check and confirm the list `System.debug('@messages => ' + messages);` is having proper email msgs crafted and proper data. It seems list is empty/data is wrong hence it might be throwing the error.

Comment: I realized the problem was related to a Visualforce component that is called by the template. The exception was being thrown inside the component's controller. Problem solved!